# How do you get Group/Permissions information for a subsite (that breaks inheritance) on a SharePoint Online Site Collection using Powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, client-object-model, groups

tl;dr version: Ultimately I can get a list of *all* Groups for a given Site Collection, but I can't tell which groups give access to which sites. Which is to say that, for a given subsite that has broken permission inheritance, I can't figure out how to get the names of that subsite's Groups (without getting the names of every other group in the site collection).

---

Hi folks, I'm trying to write a PowerShell script/function that connects to a SharePoint Online farm, iterates through each Site/SubSite/Etc and outputs the following for each:

URL to (sub)Site, Title of (Sub)Site , SharePoint Group Name , Group Access Level (Owner, Member, Visitor or similar)

When I use the function below to get the groups of a given site, it returns the groups for the entire site collection rather than just the groups for the subsite (that has broken inheritance). **What I need is to just get the groups for just the subsite (url) passed to it.**

```
function Get-Groups(){
param(
$Url = $(throw "Please provide a Site Collection or Sub-site Url who's groups you want to get."),
$Credential = $(throw "Please provide a Credentials")
)
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)  
    $context.Credentials = $Credential 
    $web = $context.Web
    $groups = $web.SiteGroups
    $context.Load($groups)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    return $groups
}
```

I've also tried using using permissions in the following code snippet to accomplish this, but I can't seem to get anything for web1.permissions (i.e. it's always null).

```
$web = Get-SPOWebs -Url 'urlOFMySite' -Credentials $credentialsDefineEarlier

foreach ($web1 in $web)
{
    #$webPerms = Get-WebPerms -Url $web.Url -Credential $SPOCredentials

    if (($web1.permissions -ne $null) -and ($web.hasuniqueroleassignments -eq "True"))
    {
    Write-Host "-----"
    Write-Host "Displaying site permissions for:  " $web1.title 
    Write-Host $web1.permissions | fl member, basepermissions
    }
    elseif ($web1.hasuniqueroleassignments -eq "False")
    {
    Write-Host "-----" 
    Write-Host "Displaying site permissions for: " $web1.title
    Write-Host $web1.title "inherits permissions from " $site.title
    }
}

function Get-SPOWebs(){
param(
    $Url = $(throw "Please provide a Site Collection Url"),
    $Credential = $(throw "Please provide a Credentials")
)
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)  
    $context.Credentials = $Credential 
    $web = $context.Web
    $context.Load($web)
    $context.Load($web.Webs)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    foreach($web in $web.Webs)
    {
        Write-Host "Outputing permsisions: " $web.permissions
        Get-SPOWebs -Url $web.Url -Credential $Credential 
        $web
    }
}
```

The Get-WebPerms (that I've tried to write) function completely doesn't work, so I've not included it here.

I've been banging my head against a wall (not literally) for a good 6 or 7 hours now with little to no progress. Any solutions/help anyone can provide would be very much appreciated. Thanks!